# Why I get conda: command not found in user though I've already installed anaconda3 in root?

Tags: software-installation, anaconda

I'm new here, I want to ask a problem I met

I have already installed Anaconda in the root system like this:

[image]

I also registered in the `/etc/profile` like this:

[image]

But I still get an error when typing `conda` in my user:

[image]

What can I do? Thank you very much!